# How do I turn off the win8.1/10 multitouch while using a touchscreen?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm currently building a C# project under Windows 8.1 Winform using a 10 points touchscreen. Is there anyway that I can turn off the multitouch and recognize it as a single touch device? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: well you could always use pointer 0 strictly (ignoring all the other points)

Comment: Thank you for reply but I don't really see the idea..

Comment: well? what do you really need this for anyways? this looks to me like a typical xy problem: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Well,the application is designed for mouse use only.So you should always keep 1 point.  For instance,it is not allowed that you push two buttons at the same time.I know this so I won't do that but others don't know and they might accidentally do that. Besides, multitouch should be banned since it brings gesture controls on Windows8.1, which is not expected.

Comment: so your question x is: „how do i run my c# application in kiosk mode?“ you might want to google for this: „Assigned Access mode“ wich is some kind of policy you can set as system administrator in order to disable gestures etc.

Comment: in order to prevent multi touch you should tell us if you use wpf or windows forms. anyways.. i guess you use wpf.. my first comment solves this problem. you need to hook into pointer events and just drop every event that is not caused by pointer id 0